# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate when downloading website content android

Tags: java, android, ssl

Im trying to download website content from the website https://songbpm.com/tiesto/red+lights however due to the certificate issue the content is not being received
The content will be later used to obtain the bpm of certain songs from an android app.

code for making the connection

```
AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost();
post.execute("https://songbpm.com/tiesto/red+lights");
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
tv.setText("Hello,"+post.get().toString()+",");
```

async http post class as it is in a separate thread

```
byte[] result = null;
String str = "";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
try {
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
     StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
        str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a while ago. I used a workaround like this one:
[Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

After adding the MySSLSocketFactory it worked without a problem.
So this might help you.

**Note: This is not a very safe solution. Only use it for testing purposes.**

Comment: I implememted it and most https sites work except the one i need which is the website songbpm.com the certificate is verified by COMODO CA Limited

Comment: i ended up with another error...  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I can't help you.

Comment: Did those other https sites work before you did the implementation?

Comment: The other https websites did not work prior to the implementation. Thanks for the help. I'm currently using a different method and it seems to be working